# How to make "checking for iconv in -liconv... no" yes

Tags: cygwin, iconv

I build httrack on Cygwin, but it is always "checking for iconv in -liconv... no" and compile error.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./.libs/libhttrack.a(htscharset.o): In function `hts_convertStringCharset':
/home/myname/httrack/src/htscharset.c:441: undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
/home/myname/httrack/src/htscharset.c:460: undefined reference to `libiconv'
/home/myname/httrack/src/htscharset.c:491: undefined reference to `libiconv_close
```

I have install libiconv1.1.4 in /usr/local/libiconv, but it's still error.

```
nm /lib/libiconv.a | grep iconv
iconv.o:
00000000 D __libiconv_version
00015960 T _iconv_canonicalize
00015120 T _libiconv
00015180 T _libiconv_close
00014d00 T _libiconv_open
000151a0 T _libiconv_open_into
00015690 T _libiconvctl
00015810 T _libiconvlist
     U _libiconv_relocate
000000d0 T _libiconv_relocate
00000000 T _libiconv_set_relocation_prefix
iconv-exports.o:
00000000 D __imp___libiconv_version
     U __libiconv_version
libiconv.res.o:
```

The code in configure for iconv check:

```
### Check for iconv
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for iconv in -liconv" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for iconv in -liconv... " >&6; }
if ${ac_cv_lib_iconv_iconv+:} false; then :
  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
  ac_check_lib_save_LIBS=$LIBS
LIBS="-liconv  $LIBS"
```

Comment: You need to look closely at configure and build logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`httrack` requires [several patches](http://cygwin-ports.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=cygwin-ports/httrack;a=tree) to build and operate correctly on Cygwin.  The libiconv patch fixes the iconv configure test to work on Cygwin (and other platforms which use GNU libiconv).